# How to train naive bayes classifier for tf-idf weighted dfm in R?

Tags: r, classification, naivebayes, quanteda

I'm new to text analysis, and I'm trying to train a naive bayes classifier for a dataset from `quanteda` using the following codes:

```
library("quanteda")

data(data_corpus_amicus, package = "quanteda.corpora")

# set training class
trainclass <- docvars(data_corpus_amicus, "trainclass")
amicus_train <- which(trainclass == "P" | trainclass == "R" )

# set test class
testclass  <- docvars(data_corpus_amicus, "testclass")
amicus_test <- which(testclass == "AP" | testclass == "AR")

# create dfm from the data
amicus_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_amicus, verbose = FALSE)
```

I wanted to train the classifier for a `tf-idf` weighed dfm so I tried the following:

```
amicus_dfm_weight <- dfm_tfidf(amicus_dfm, scheme_tf = "count", scheme_df = "inverse") 

weight_nb <-textmodel_nb(amicus_dfm_weight[amicus_train,], docvars(data_corpus_amicus, "trainclass")[amicus_train])
```

The above code give me error `Error: will not group a weighted dfm; use force = TRUE to override`, so I also tried `amicus_dfm_weight <- dfm_tfidf(amicus_dfm, scheme_tf = "count", scheme_df = "inverse", force = TRUE)` but it still comes up with the same error.

Does anyone know what does that error mean and how to fix the error?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes: install the newest **quanteda.textmodels** (>= 0.9.1) package, where `textmodel_nb()` now lives. This issue has been fixed. In the future please consider using `reprex::reprex()` for reproducible examples, and always include the package versions in the output or explanation.

This would have been more appropriate as a GitHub issue than as a SO question.